# angular promise returning __proto__

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an asp.net-mvc app using angular. I had a get method that returns some data from the server. What I was returning was a `Tuple` with a status message and a second piece of data that was either an error message or the actual data. Ex:

```
return Json(new Tuple<string, string>("error", "bad request"));
//or 
return Json(new Tuple<string, MyData>("success", new MyData());
```

this was working fine, in angular I did the following:

```
$http.get(url).then(
            function (result) {
                return result.data;
            },
            function (result) {
                $q.reject(result.data);
            }
```

here, `result.data.Item1` was the first item of my `Tuple`

However, I changed my return types from `Tuple` to a new custom type that I created that looks like the following:

```
public class ServerResponse <T1, T2, T3>
    {
        T1 status { get; set; }
        T2 message { get; set; }
        T3 data { get; set; }
        public ServerResponse(T1 status, T2 message, T3 data)
        {
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

but now when I do:

```
result.data.status
```

I dont get expected results because `result.data` is returning something like this:

```
__proto__ : Object
```

and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking around and comparing to the `Tuple` class, I noticed that my `ServerResponse` class's properties were not marked `public` so they weren't being found. After making them `public` the problem went away